# Getting a "bound method" error with my login form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

So my register form works fine, it successfully creates a new user. However my login form cannot log a user in. So when I log in with username/password entered correctly, and `print(form.non_field_errors)` in my view, I get this error:

```
<bound method BaseForm.non_field_errors of <UserLoginForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(username;password)>>
```

Can somebody tell me what this means? So the login form is invalid but not sure why. And when I `print(form.errors)` in the same view I get this error:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>username<ul class="errorlist"><li>A user with that username already exists.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Also, keep in mind these register and login functions don't have a seperate url, they are all on on the homepage (accessible via javascript onclick, to prevent page refresh). Here's my code:

**views.py**

```
def boxes_view(request):

    ...


    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)

    form_login = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        print('LOGGED IN')

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'form_login': form_login
    }

    return render(request, 'polls.html', context)


def register(request):
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email)
        user.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        print(form.non_field_errors)
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return redirect('/')


def user_login(request):
    form_login = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form_login.is_valid():
        username = form_login.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form_login.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        print(form_login.errors)
        print(form_login.non_field_errors)
        form_login = UserLoginForm()
    return redirect('/')
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = [
            'username',
            'password',
        ]


class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'confirm_password',
        ]

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        current_emails = User.objects.filter(email=email)

        if current_emails.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("That email is taken")
```

**base.html** #parent of polls.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'user_login' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="loginBox">
        {{ form_login.username|placeholder:"username" }}
        {{ form_login.password|placeholder:"password" }}

        <input type="submit" value="login" style="margin-left: 10px"/>
    </div>
</form>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'register' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="registerBox">
        {{ form.username|placeholder:"username" }}
        {{ form.email|placeholder:"email" }}
        {{ form.password|placeholder:"password" }}
        {{ form.confirm_password|placeholder:"confirm password" }}

        <input type="submit" value="register" />

    </div>
</form>
```

**urls.py**

BV = views.boxes_view

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', BV, name='news'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    url(r'^post/', include('post.urls')),
    url(r'^user_login/', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
    url(r'^logout/', logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^register/', views.register, name='register'),

]
```

Comment: Could you post your `urls.py`?

Comment: Can you also put your urls.py for login and registration urls..?? I think the problem is that login is getting mixed up with the registration process.

Comment: Just added in `urls.py`, which includes the `user_login` and `register` urls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is you are using ModefForm for login view. ModelForm performs [validation the model instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform) which throws non-unique error.
Try to use simple form like this:

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Comment: Good catch. ModelForm is for creation or editing of Django models, not transactional logic like login.

Comment: Yep this fixes the problem, thankyou very much. Should UserRegistrationForm be `forms.Form` aswell or doesn't matter? Both of them work.

Comment: @Zorgan you are welcome:) As for registration form, you can use modelForm since it's creating new User object in DB.